# Java:Apache commons mail goes immediately to hotmail junk folder

Tags: java, email, hotmail, apache-commons-email

Is there a way to make my email pass through these hotmail filters?
In gmail the mails arrive in the inbox folder

Comment: Read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html :)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say :) one up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your email look less like spam. MS provides some [tips](http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same problem, But I Modified the flow like 
1) Once the registered user, we will send a confirmation mail to their inbox and ask the user to respond back to the same Mail.
So that Hotmail or gmail wont think your mail as Spam/JUnk. IN that way you can prevent the mails going to SPam or Junk folder.

Or one more way is to tell people as " to Mark this mail as NOT SPAM" some where in your application.

I hope this might help, if you have the similar kind of application.